# React useEffect keeps fetching

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm using `useEffect` to fetch data from DB and later the code displays that list of data.

```javascript
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("triggered")
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/group/getAll")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      setGroups(data)
    })
  })
```

I noticed that `triggered` got printed to console thousands of times in a couple seconds so I'm assuming it's constantly sending request to the DB.

[image]

Is this the expected behavior? And if not, how to I fix it?

p.s. I know with the `[]` parameter it only renders once. But is there a way to make useEffect work correctly (only fetch data when `groups` rerenders on the webpage)

-----edit-----

This is how I used groups

```
  const createGroup = groups.map((group, i) => {
    return (
      <Dropdown.Item 
        key = {i}
        onClick = {showUser}
        id = {group["groupId"]}
      >
      {group["groupName"]}
      </Dropdown.Item> 
    )
  })
```

And `createGroup`

```
<Dropdown.Menu>
  {createGroup}
</Dropdown.Menu>
```

----edit2-------
I understand how dependency arrays work. I tried `[groups]` but that didn't change anything. I also tried `[createGroup]` but got an error because the function was not initialized at first. Can I add an HTML element or something to the dependency array? With the structure of my code what exactly should I put in there?

Comment: always add a dependency array to the `useEffect` else it will re-run everytime

Comment: I'm not sure `groups` rerenders on the webpage, you need to give more context about the situation that you need to rerender your component

Comment: @NickVu It's rendered later in a function (see my new edit)

Comment: @Nathan you want to fetch data to change `groups` state, and then listen to `groups` state change to fetch data again. It's like an infinite loop. You should give the condition that's when you want to **fetch data** for `groups`

Comment: Shouldn't you trigger the API from the onClick handler in Dropdown.Item?

Answer (score 2):

You should specify, the state variables or the props, which when changed should trigger the useEffect, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("triggered")
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/group/getAll")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      setGroups(data)
    })
  }, [x , y]);
```

Here `x` and `y`, can be state variables, props, or both. Only when the values of these will change, then the useEffect will trigger.

Comment: I tried `[groups]` but that didn't change anything for me. `[]` makes it so that it only fetches once but that's not what I wanted.

Comment: You are setting the `group` state variable value, from the API response. It will trigger the useEffect, you will have to use something else

Answer (score 1):

Regarding:

> I noticed that triggered got printed to console thousands of times in a couple seconds so I'm assuming it's constantly sending request to the DB.

This has already been answered, and no, for your use case, this isn't the expected behavior since you seem to want to fetch data from the DB,

```js
fetch("http://localhost:8080/group/getAll")
```

collect the JSON,

```js
.then(response => response.json())
```

and set a state variable using `setGroups`

```js
.then(data => {
  setGroups(data)
})
```

That said, regarding:

> But is there a way to make useEffect work correctly (only fetch data when groups rerenders on the webpage)

How *do* you want the `useEffect` to *work correctly* ?

Per its usage in your code, it seems to working as designed. If you want to trigger a re-render using `useEffect` you are going to want another state variable other than `groups`, which, as many commentators and users pointed out, is going to cause an infinite loop.

Ask yourself: Do you want the API call to be made again? (and hence the re-render) *based on the selection* of a `group` from `<Dropdown>`?

Then the value that was selected in the `<Dropdown>` needs to be passed to the dependency array of `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should understand component lifecycle concepts first (probably with class components), then understand how lifecycle can be replicated with hooks and functional components.

I put here an explanation, I hope this explanation could be helpful.

Please, compare these three snippets:

Snippet #1:

```js
// This snippet (#1) runs on every render because there is no dependencies.
// So if the component gets updated then it will be re-rendered.
// Consequently, this effect will be fired again (and again if the effect updates the component state).
useEffect(() => {
    // fetch logic [...]
    console.log("runs every time component is re-rendered");
});
```

Snippet #2:

```js
// This snippet (#2) runs on mount. It's similar to componentDidMount on class components.
// Notice there is an empty array of dependencies as a second argument.
// You can fetch data when page is loaded with this snippet.
useEffect(() => {
    // fetch logic [...]
    console.log("runs only when component was mounted");
}, []);
```

Snippet #3:

```js
// This snippet (#3) runs when values on dependency array change, like url variable.
// You can select your array of dependencies. Be aware when some dependency gets updated.
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("triggered only when dependencies change")
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        setGroups(data)
    })
}, [url]);
```

Have a great day!